# How to substract every nth from (n+3)th line in awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I have 4 column data files which have approximately 100 lines. I'd like to substract every nth from (n+3)th line and print the values in a new column ($5). The column data has not a regular pattern for each column.

My sample file:

```
cat input
1   2   3   20
1   2   3   10
1   2   3   5
1   2   3   20
1   2   3   30
1   2   3   40
1   2   3    .
1   2   3    .
1   2   3    . (and so on)
```

Output should be:

```
1   2   3   20  0  #(20-20)
1   2   3   10  20  #(30-10)
1   2   3   5   35  #(40-5)
1   2   3   20  ?  #(. - 20)
1   2   3   30  ?  #(. - 30)
1   2   3   40  ?  #(. - 40)
1   2   3       .   
1   2   3       .   
1   2   3       . (and so on)
```

How can i do this in awk? 
Thank you

Comment: What have you done up to now?

Comment: I tried getline and arrays but i couldn't solve it.

Comment: Show what you've done and people can help you with it.

Comment: For example: I am using to subtract every nth from (n+1)th line for their absolute value. awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";a=0} {if (($4-a) < 0) print $1, $2, $3, $4, -1*($4-a); else print $1, $2, $3, $4, $4-a;} {a=$4}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I think the easiest thing is to read through the file twice. The first time (the `NR==FNR` block) we save all the 4th column values in an array indexed by the line number. The next block is executed for the second pass and creates a 5th column with the desired calculation (checking first to make sure that we wouldn't go passed the end of the file).

```
$ cat input
1   2   3   20
1   2   3   10
1   2   3   5
1   2   3   20
1   2   3   30
1   2   3   40

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$4; last=NR; next} {$5 = (FNR+3 <= last ? a[FNR+3] - $4 : "")}1' input input
1  2  3  20  0
1  2  3  10  20
1  2  3  5   35
1  2  3  20
1  2  3  30
1  2  3  40
```

Comment: This works... And I think FNR idea is perfect. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `tac + awk + tac`:

```
tac input |
awk '{a[NR]=$4} NR>3 { $5 = (a[NR-3] ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ? a[NR-3] - $4 : "?") } 1' |
tac | column -t

1  2  3  20  0
1  2  3  10  20
1  2  3  5   35
1  2  3  20  ?
1  2  3  30  ?
1  2  3  40  ?
1  2  3  .
1  2  3  .
1  2  3  .
```